# Ordered partitions of positive integer N

Tags: combinatorics

What is number of ordered partitions of a positive integer $N$?
I see that

```
1 = 1,

2 = 2, 1+1,

3 = 3, 2+1, 1+2, 1+1+1,

4 = 4, 3+1, 1+3, 2+2, 2+1+1, 1+2+1, 1+1+2, 1+1+1+1,
```

So far we observe that that $N$ has $2^{N-1}$ ordered partition.

I tried to prove the result with induction but could not proceed with the inductive hypothesis.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you think of two ways to obtain an ordered partition of $N$ from an ordered partition of $N-1$ such that a) no partition obtained by the first method is obtained by the second, and b) every partition is obtained in one of these ways?

Comment: Givea a partition p of N-1,i can write N=p+1 or merge 1 with one of the terms of p.But then how this solves my problem.

Comment: Very good so far. Now choose with which term you want to merge.

Comment: and then what do i do

Comment: "Ordered partitions" of integer $N\gt 0$ are more properly called [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 6):

These are called [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) and there are $2^{N - 1}$ of them for $N$. To see this note that a composition is the same thing as choosing a way to put bars in between stars:

e.g. 1 + 3 + 2 + 1 corresponds to * | * * * | * * | *

There are $N - 1$ gaps and you are selecting a subset of these. Thus there are

$$ {N - 1 \choose k - 1}$$

compositions of $N$ with $k$ parts and

$$ 2^{N - 1} $$

compositions of $N$ with any number of parts.

---

The inductive argument:

You can either put a $+ 1$ at the end or merge the $1$ into the last part. Then argue that every composition of $N$ is obtained in exactly one of these ways (i.e. given a composition of $N$, figure out whether it came from adding $1$ or merging $1$). So you have two inclusions $$ \{\text{compositions of } N - 1\} \longrightarrow \{\text{compositions of } N \} $$ whose images are disjoint but their union is everything (can you see how this follows?). Therefore there are twice as many compositions of $N$ as there are $N - 1$.